# Fastest way to find item in array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3

What's the fastest way to find the index of an item in a list or object in Javascript / AS3? I'm asking this for both because the syntax is similar for both these languages.

Assuming:

```
myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
myObject = {one:1, two:2, three:3};
```

Which is the fastest and in which case would you want it or not?

- Array.indexOf(x)
- myObject[x] != null
- x in myObject
- something else?

Comment: usually, using primitive arrays and accessing using bracket notation is the fastest. but I'm sure a simple Google search will come up with your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an object doesn't sound like a good idea, as re-indexing will be a heavy operation and will wipe out the access performance gains if any. Array.indexOf(x) seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are implemented using efficient hash tables, so looking up a key will be O(1). If your values to "find" are strings and their positions are static, this will be quite fast. Checking for boolean existance can be done with `key in obj`, getting the stored index will be `obj[key] || -1`.

If you're searching for more complex objects (which are not serializable to strings easily), you will need to use an Array. `Array.indexOf` does a search with O(n), which is okay if you don't do it too often. Checking for existance will be `arr.indexOf(item) != -1`, getting the index just `arr.indexOf(item)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some tests on native indexOf and binary search of needed index.
Here are results on 10 000 items array.

- value | IndexOf | binary search
- 1     | 0.003   | 0.013
- 5000  | 1.546   | 0.016
- 9990  | 3.105   | 0.015

Test are done in node v8 environment, but seems native indexOf is using loop to find needed index.
Here are a link to binary search http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/08/searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/