# iterating on an array vs an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Which one is faster: iterating over a an array or an object. And what happens when i need to perform action such as deleting any element from in between?

```
var a = {"A1":1, "B1":2, "C1":3};
```

or

```
var a = ["A1", "B1", "C1"];
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json collection".  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  That's a JavaScript object, nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: sry for that but I need to know which one is faster.

Comment: More fun facts: An array *is* an object.  It just happens to be an object with property names that look like numbers.

Comment: I guess it depends, but my experience is that iterating over arrays is a lot faster than iterating over objects, almost all the time. You could always just try it on [**JSPERF**](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-iterate)

Comment: Faster on what?  Where?  What do you mean "what happens"?  Bytes in RAM change?  Pixels on screen changes?

Comment: In real life, if that helps you out ?

Comment: @djechlin in terms of performance, intructions etc.

Comment: @cHao an array also has a `.length` property which is maintained by the interpreter.

Comment: @Alnitak: Which needs no maintenance unless you're adding or removing elements.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Aside from the fact that you use `for (var i in a)` without `a.hasOwnProperty(i)`, it looks legit.  :)

Comment: @cHao `a.hasOwnProperty()` is not required in modern ES5 code.  People should get out of the habit of using it.

Comment: @cHao: I didn't like that test.  I think the `console.log` was skewing the numbers.  Also, IE didn't like it much.  @adeneo made one: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-iterate

Comment: related: [Fastest way to find item in array/object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757360/fastest-way-to-find-item-in-array-object)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I'd argue that the `console.log` version is more realistic.  No one's just going to iterate through a bunch of properties and then not *do* anything with them.  If you care about doing nothing but that, then a benchmark borders on irrelevance.  The difference between the two easily becomes noise once you actually do useful work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating over arrays should be faster than iterating over an object, but it'll depend on:

1. the size of the object / array
2. whether your keys are contigious
3. all sorts of other optimiser crap

On older browsers, removing elements from an array used to be very expensive (because it required changing the key on every subsequent element) but on modern browsers that's less of a problem.

Seriously, just use whichever is the best representation for your project, and then worry about optimisation later *if* it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Which one is faster - iterrating over a an array or an object?

The array might be stored more efficient, and also its indices are predictable (no lookup needed). It should be faster, but you won't notice a difference on small sets.

> And what happens when i need to perform action such as deleting any element from in between?

That's easy with an object; you just call `delete a.A1;`. It's a `O(1)` operation.

With an array, using `a.splice(1,1);`, there needs to happen a renaming of all items, which is rather slow if happening often (`O(n)`).

Answer (score 1):

One isn't faster or slower than the other.  Use whichever one makes the most sense for your project.

As for removing, for arrays look at [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), and for objects try [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: but isnt it that if i splice from array the whole index get shuffled after the deleted element.

Comment: @jason: If that matters to you, then use an object.  Use whichever makes more sense in your project.